# Can't apply try except pass codes to map function

Tags: google-colaboratory, libgee

How can I apply try, expect, pass codes to map() function in python? Is there any help for me?

```
Result=ImageCollection.map(function)
```

Comment: apply a try/except for each the element given to map ? what type is "ImageCollection" ?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. Can you please ad more details about exactly what you need to accomplish? Presumably, this is using `pandas`? Please see [ask] and the [help]

Comment: Images that should not be from the images used by the code in the imagecollection, my aim is to extract these images with the "try expect pass" command.